# How does ACE_Remote_Mutex work?

Tags: token, ace

I wrote two small programs which tried to acquire the same Remote Mutex named "The Token":

```
ACE_Remote_Mutex token("The Token", 1, 1);
token.acquire();
ACE_OS::sleep(5);
token.release();
return 0;
```

Both of them got the following debug output:

```
(3078597488) acquired The Token
(4243|3078597488) BIG PROBLEMS with get_connection: Connection refused
error on remote acquire, releasing shadow mutex.
(3078597488) released The Token, owner is no owner
(4243|3078597488) BIG PROBLEMS with get_connection: Connection refused
(3078597488) release failed: Permission denied.
(3078597488) shadow: release failed
```

Does ACE_Remote_Mutex work only with some sort of "agent" like Corba broker? Can I modify my code?

Comment: The word "remote" in the method name might be your first clue...

Answer (score 0):

Remote_Mutex uses Token Service to acquire lock. Token Service is not a CORBA service but it plays a role similar to it. Here is an example of svc.conf entry that starts Token Service dynamically:

```
dynamic Token_Service Service_Object * 
          ../lib/netsvcs:_make_ACE_Token_Acceptor() 
          "-p 10202"
```